# Sylius - Product Builder not using expected Entity (override)

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to create a Sylius product with the product builder.
When I try to build a product I get the following error:

```
Found entity of type Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant on association
Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Product#variants, but expecting
Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Variant
```

I'm trying to build a product with the below code snippet:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/products/create", name="sf_product_create")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $product = $this->get('sylius.builder.product')
        ->create('My Lovely Product')
        ->setPrice(18790)
        ->setDescription('Such a lovely product.')
        ->addProperty('color', 'Red')
        ->save()
    ;

    return array('product' => $product);
}
```

I've overridden the `SyliusProduct` as such:

```
use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Product as BaseProduct;

class Product extends BaseProduct
{
    protected $resource; // going to do something with this later on.
}
```

The `SyliusVariant` has been overriden in a similar fashion:

```
use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant as BaseVariant;

class Variant extends BaseVariant {
    protected $salePrice;

    // ... + getSalePrice() & setSalePrice()
}
```

I've updated the config file in `sylius.yml` to use my own classes:

```
sylius_product:
    classes:
        product:
            model: Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Product
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\ProductController
            repository: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
            form: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ProductType

sylius_variable_product:
    classes:
        variant:
            model: Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Variant
            repository: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository\VariantRepository
            form: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\VariantType
```

Why is it using the `Sylius` variant for its association while it properly expects an instance of my own `Variant`?

**Edit**

Here's my Product mapping:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Product" table="sylius_product">
        <one-to-many field="variants" target-entity="Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Variant" mapped-by="product">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you please post mapping data for `Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Product`?

Comment: I had tried some custom mapping for the Product, but it did not seem to be able to override the `variants` property.. I've added it to the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a little bug, but you can easily work around it by overriding the constructor in your own Product class.

CoreBundle\Model\Product:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setMasterVariant(new Variant());
    $this->taxons = new ArrayCollection();

    $this->variantSelectionMethod = self::VARIANT_SELECTION_CHOICE;
}
```

The Master Variant is set to an instance of CoreBundle\Model\Variant.
Override the constructor in your own Product model:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setMasterVariant(new YourCustomVariant());
}
```

This should probably be fixed though :).

Comment: Hi Ruud, thanks for your reply. This does solve the `unexpected class` exception, however this approach causes the price to not be set properly: `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'price' cannot be null` even though I have called `setPrice()` on the Product Builder. Any clue what's up with this?

Comment: It's interesting to note that `$product->getPrice()` does return `18790`, without calling `save()`. Is there some other variant that might ruin things?

Comment: I've just updated my answer a bit, because copying the whole constructor is not very clean. The price problem shouldn't have anything to do with this override though.

Comment: Oddly enough my Product gets saved properly when the `sylius_product.classes.model` is set to `Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Product`, but gives the above error when set to `Shopfish\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Product`..

Comment: The price problem might result from some duplicate association with variants. You are redefining an existing association. Try removing it (as the product mapping is then empty, you might even be able to remove the mapping altogether, but I don't know if Doctrine accepts that)

Answer (score 2):

To follow latest sylius dev you need to extend Products model and also replace __construct with the below code

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this
        ->setVariants(new ArrayCollection())
        ->setMasterVariant(new YourCustomVariant())
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I'm sorry to say your answer is merely a code-snippet which is not self-explanatory and could use some explanation. Besides that an answer was already accepted. Thanks though :-).

Comment: For sure, add some explanation lines. As well there is small difference, important to clear variants before set master

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, makes much more sense now!